# Override after model->save() Active Record

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, yii

I have this loop for save records with Active record:

```
foreach ($array as $value) {
     $modelImagen->url = $value;
     $modelImagen->inmueble_id_inmueble = '1';
     $modelImagen->save();
}
```

And i have the problem saves only one record, i think that maybe override the data and saves the last one. Maybe i have a problem with the loop? All the tables id are autoincremental.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

initiate the model in every loop and `unset` after save

Here is your code should be

```
foreach ($array as $value) {
     $modelImagen  = new yourmodelName();  // initiate your model
     $modelImagen->url = $value;
     $modelImagen->inmueble_id_inmueble = '1';
     $modelImagen->save();
     unset($modelImagen); // do unset 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create additional records/rows, your current loop overwrites the same record/row.

You can use either of the following methods to save all url values in new rows

```
foreach ($array as $value) {
     $modelImagen = new ModelImagen() // Your model class
     $modelImagen->url = $value;
     $modelImagen->inmueble_id_inmueble = '1';
     $modelImagen->save();
}
```

or you can use `insert` method, note that validation is not performed in `insert` method, you will have call `validate()` separately if you want validation to be performed

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to new AR in the loop. e.g. $modelImagen=new Model;